Bigquery table does not get updated, view with the same schema shows correct data
I have a cloud scheduler job that runs every morning to update a set of tables. There is a view and a table which have the same code and schema. The table does not show the updated data like the view. The table updates when i run the schedule manually. The code runs on dbt through cloud scheduler
I have tried moving the schedule to a later time to check if there is a lag in updating the dependent tables, it hasnt proven helpful. I am not sure what could be the reason. Can anyone help?
